# Use htmlwebpackplugin.files as a JSON

Tags: webpack, notation, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to use webpack with htmlwebpackplugin. I have seen the documetation in https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin and in the part of "Writing Your Own Templates" is said that I can use some variables in templates, like htmlWebpackPlugin.files or htmlWebpackPlugin.options. Ok.

When I try to use the example of htmlWebpackPlugin.files on the template, it fails because it is not code that I have to put between <% and %>. However, I can do the same, but not using the JSON format, but the dot notation instead. SO I only ask if the example is only for to have a reference or I really need to use the dot notation, as I see in other examples.

Forgive my ignorance, thank you

Comment: Can you show a concrete example what you're trying to do?

Comment: I mean only If I need to use it as a JSON, because the example shows as in the URL, like "htmlWebpackPlugin": {
  "files": {
    "css": [ "main.css" ],
    "js": [ "assets/head_bundle.js", "assets/main_bundle.js"],
    "chunks": {
      "head": {
        "entry": "assets/head_bundle.js",
        "css": [ "main.css" ]
      },
      "main": {
        "entry": "assets/main_bundle.js",
        "css": []
      },
    }
  }
}

Comment: I know that I can use <% ... %>, but in that case I need to use dot notation, like "htmlwebpackplugin.files", not like "htmlWebpackPlugin: { files: { ... } }"